# Select+Checkboxes fields = query a Database

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to make a form which contains one select field (dates) and multiple checkbox fields (teams), so when I select a date or choose a team, automatically makes a query a database, filtering by the selected date and teams. However, I don't know where I have to start, so any advise would be greatful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In what form does the data exist if at all?  Do you have custom tables already setup, or are you already using something else, or have you not even got that far?  Are you looking for an out of the box solution or looking to build something from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

[RSForms Pro](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/rsform-pro/) is very powerful and can do this.  There are a few steps to it.  When you make your fields, you would [auto-populate](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/custom-scripting/auto-populate-a-list-from-a-table.html) the available teams by using RSForms built in shortcode for the query.  Then you actually post the data and [grab it back](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/frequently-asked-questions/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-through-the-url-and-how-can-i-catch-it-.html).

You could display the data in other fields or probably clearer to do with javascript innerHTLML similar to this [tutorial](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/custom-scripting/preview-data-before-submit.html) although you would probably need to loop it if you wanted to display it like a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a search form and add some custom code to query the database and display the results using many of the [forms extensions in the Joomla Extensions Database](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/contacts-and-feedback/forms) e.g. [ChronoForms](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/chronoforms).

Check the [FAQs](http://www.chronoengine.com/faqs.html) and the [Forums](http://www.chronoengine.com/forums.html) for the latest examples.